# VS Code Printing Terminal Sign at the end

Tags: c++, arrays, terminal, compilation

I'm new to using Visual Studio Code and noticed upon outputting code. For a code that prints the values in an array.

```
int arr[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   arr[i] = i;
   std::cout<<arr[i];
}
```

I will get an output of:
01234%
where the "%" is highlighted. I've noticed it's the same as my terminal symbol. I would like to know how to remove it. I'm using g++ to compile and ./a.out to run.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Add `std::cout << "\n";` after your loop to print a newline.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!